# Move to next record using oledbdatareader C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb, datareader

I have created a method where I can search an access database using oledbdatareader however i can't seem to work out how i can move to the next record using a button.

Please help!

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=BoilerSvc_be.mdb";
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Equipment.CustID AS CustID,Equipment.Manufacturer AS Manufacturer,Equipment.Model AS Model, Equipment.LastService AS LastService,Initial,Surname,[Address 1],[Address 2],[Address 3],[Post Town],[Post Code],Telephone FROM Contacts INNER JOIN Equipment ON Equipment.CustID = Contacts.CustID WHERE Surname = '" +  textBox12.Text + "' OR Initial = '" + textBox12.Text +  "' OR[Post Town] = '" + textBox12.Text + "' OR[Post Code] = '" + textBox12 + "'", conn);
            command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Name", textBox12));
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                FirstName.Text = reader["Initial"].ToString();
                LastName.Text = reader["Surname"].ToString();
                Address1.Text = reader["Address 1"].ToString();
                Address2.Text = reader["Address 2"].ToString();
                Address3.Text = reader["Address 3"].ToString();
                TownCity.Text = reader["Post Town"].ToString();
                PostCode.Text = reader["Post Code"].ToString();
                Telephone.Text = reader["Telephone"].ToString();
                LstSvcDat.Text = reader["LastService"].ToString();
                BoilerMan.Text = reader["Manufacturer"].ToString();
                BoilerMod.Text = reader["Model"].ToString();
            }
            // Insert code to process data.
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are moving to the next record when you call `reader.Read()`, would suggest loading the data you need rather than reading the next record from the database based off of user input.

This is how you do that

Should define a DtoObject containing all of your fields first

```
public class DtoObject
{
    public string FirstName { get; set;}
    public string LastName  { get; set;}
    public string Address1  { get; set;}
    public string Address2  { get; set;}
    public string Address3  { get; set;}
    public string TownCity  { get; set;}
    public string PostCode  { get; set;}
    public string Telephone { get; set;}
    public string LstSvcDat { get; set;}
    public string BoilerMan { get; set;}
    public string BoilerMod { get; set;} 
}
```

Then in your method add a list of the Dtos, and a method to load them to the valid Form Inputs, and methods to move forward and backwards an item

```
//in your class
private readonly List<DtoObject> _ls = new List<DtoObject>();
private int _currentIndex = 0;


private void LoadDto(DtoObject object)
{
    FirstName.Text = reader["Initial"].ToString();
    LastName.Text = reader["Surname"].ToString();
    ...
    BoilerMod.Text = reader["Model"].ToString();
}


private void MoveToNextItem()
{
   _currentIndex++;
   LoadDtoObject(_ls[_currentIndex]);
}

private void MoveToPreviousItem()
{
   _currentIndex--;
   LoadDtoObject(_ls[_currentIndex]);
}
```

Then inside your method to read just read all of them into the list and initialize the value to the first index

```
//clear existing data
_ls.Clear();            

while (reader.Read())
{

     var current = new DtoObject();

     current.FirstName = reader["Initial"].ToString();
     current.LastName = reader["Surname"].ToString();
     current.Address1= reader["Address 1"].ToString();
     current.Address2= reader["Address 2"].ToString();
     current.Address3= reader["Address 3"].ToString();
     current.TownCity= reader["Post Town"].ToString();
     current.PostCode= reader["Post Code"].ToString();
     current.Telephone= reader["Telephone"].ToString();
     current.LstSvcDat= reader["LastService"].ToString();
     current.BoilerMan= reader["Manufacturer"].ToString();
     current.BoilerMod= reader["Model"].ToString();  

     _ls.Add(current);
}  

//if there are any set the first values to current form
if(_ls.Any())
{
    _currentIndex = 0;
    LoadDto(_ls.First());
}
else
{
    //do something to notify no records were found
}
```

Then create your event handler

```
private void nextItemButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    MoveToNextItem();
}

private void prevItemButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    MoveToPreviousItem();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to move everything except `reader.Read()` out of the click handler. Then, the first time the button is clicked (or on startup or load), open the reader. When someone clicks the button, you `Read` on record.

Right now, you are opening the reader, reading all of the data, then closing the reader each time someone clicks the button.